# Prove that $\lim_{n→\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}{n}=1$ using "$\varepsilon \to N$" definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

how to prove this equation with the "$\varepsilon \to N$"  definition?  I feel have some trouble.Thanks!

> $\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}{n}=1\\$

I complete my solution:
when $a=0$ it's obviously true. When
$a \neq 0$: $$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}{n}-1&=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}{n}-\frac{n}{n}
\\&=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}-\sqrt{n^2}}{n}\\&=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n}\lt\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{n^2}+n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\lt\frac{a^2}{n(\sqrt{n^2}+\sqrt{n^2})}=\frac{a^2}{2n}
\\ for\quad \forall \varepsilon \gt0, \quad when\quad \frac{a^2}{2N^2}\lt \varepsilon, \mathit N\gt \frac{a}{\sqrt{2\varepsilon}}+1,|\frac{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}{n}-1|\lt\varepsilon.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)")

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Please add your attempt into the question itself, not as a comment below the question. You can do that by editing the question.

Comment: Since this is a limit as $n\to\infty,$ try to see *why* the result is true for large values of $n$, and then try to prove it is true for all $n$ greater than or equal to some integer $N.$

Comment: Your proof attempt is good and almost complete (you have done the hard part). You just need to Add the details (the $\varepsilon, N$ stuff- which comes from the definition of a limit) and write a conclusion (which should be the result).

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks a lot! I feel confused about the last part. Im trying to figure out.

Comment: @RamanujanXV Because I need to "find out" an "N" .

Comment: If you do not care for optimal value of $N$ with respect to $\varepsilon$  you can use $\sqrt{n^2+a^2}\le n+|a|.$

Comment: OHHH thanks ALOT!! I get it!!@RyszardSzwarc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is almost complete. First, two minor issues.

One, I would add one more line to explain how you got from

$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}-\sqrt{n^2}}{n}$$

to
$$\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}+n}$$

but in general, the inequality you got is correct.

Two, there is no need to separate the case that $a=0$. The inequality you got is true for all $a$, including $a=0$.

---

Now, you only need to "put it all together". Let's call $a_n$ the $n$-th element of your sequence. Then you aready know that, for any $n$, you have $$a_n - 1 < \frac{a^2}{n(\sqrt{n^2} + n)}$$

Now, you need to prove that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N$ such that if $n>N$, then $|a_n - 1| < \epsilon$.

Well, any such proof will probably start with the famous words: **Let $\epsilon > 0$**.

Then, consider what happens if $N$ is so big that $\frac{a^2}{n(\sqrt{n^2}+n)} < \epsilon$. Surely, such a value of $N$ exists (why?).

If you have such an $N$, what can you say about $a_n-1$?

Comment: Wow!! I get it finally!! Thanks A LOT!!!

Comment: @ToadetteK Don't thank me, thank yourself. You did all the hard work, you just needed to realize that you are inches away from the finish line.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to MSE.
another point of view may help.
Taylor expansion for $$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}2-\frac{x^2}{8}+o(x^3)$$and
$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}{\sqrt {n^2}}=\sqrt{1+(\frac{a}{n})^2}\\=1+\frac 12(\frac{a}{n})^2 -\frac 18(\frac{a}{n})^4+...\\\geq 1+\frac 12(\frac{a}{n})^2$$ so
$$|\frac{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}{n}-1|<\epsilon\\\frac12(\frac{a}{n})^2<\epsilon$$ and  ...

Comment: Oh, here's another solution! Thanks!!